# not set value in formArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have edit page in angular 8 . in this page i have a formArray and i need fill it .

i set value form with formArray .

now i use this code for set value :

ts :

```
createForm(): void {
    this.editQuestionFG = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(this.questions.title, Validators.required),
      courseExamId: new FormControl(this.questions.courseExamId, Validators.required),
      courseOptions: this._formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }


  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      optionTitle: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      isCorrect: new FormControl(true, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  setItem(item: Options[]) {
    const formArray = new FormArray([]);
    for (let x of item) {
      formArray.push(this._formBuilder.group({
        isCorrect: x.isCorrect,
        optionTitle: x.optionTitle
      }));
    }
    this.editQuestionFG.setControl('courseOptions', formArray);
    console.log(this.editQuestionFG.controls['courseOptions'].value)
  }
```

and this is html code :

```
 <div class="answer col-lg-12 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
                        <div formArrayName="courseOptions" class="row m-auto"
                            *ngFor="let project of editQuestionFG.get('courseOptions').controls; let i = index">
                            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="col-lg-1 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile icon remove text-center">
                                    <label (click)="deleteItem(i)"><i class="la la-trash"></i></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput formControlName="optionTitle"
                                            [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile icon">
                                    <mat-radio-group name="radp" aria-label="Select an option"
                                        formControlName="isCorrect">
                                        <mat-radio-button value='true'>صحیح</mat-radio-button>
                                    </mat-radio-group>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-Item">
                            <button (click)="AddItems()" mat-raised-button type="button"
                                color="accent">{{'COURSE_QUESTION.ADD_NEW_OPTION' |translate}}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

when i use this code it fill the `optionTitle` but it not set the `isCorrect`  in radio-button value .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve that????**

Comment: in order to you radio button to be checked you need to fill the checked attribute  


<input type="radio" formControlName="formName" name="somename" value="somevalue" [checked]="varible_name==='some_value'">

Comment: @EugeneSunic please show me with my code

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could create a Stackblitz example of the same.